# Should I use repeated meaure ANOVA?

Tags: statistical-significance, anova, post-hoc

I have 5 interaction techniques (eg., interaction 1 to 5) and I have recruited 15 participants to participate in my study. Each participant interacts with each of these 5 techniques only once. I will record the time it took each participant interact with each technique. Thus, as a result I will have a following table:

[image]

I want to know whether there is a significant difference between any of these interaction techniques. Thus, should I apply repeated measure ANOVA since each of the participants performs each of the techniques?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, repeated measures ANOVA seems like the best analysis for the data.  Each subject is given multiple treatments sequentially. Your screen shot is too small to read, but the repeated measures approach helps when some subjects (in this example) take longer for all tasks and others take less time for all tasks, so you want to look at the difference from task to task in each subject, rather than just compare the average time for each task.

ANOVA is based on Gaussian distributions. Is time-to-complete-task likely to be close to Gaussian? OR perhaps speed, which is proportional to the reciprocal of time is closer to Gaussian?

Comment: Thanks Harvey. Explanation about the table. Columns of the table show subjects/users (e.g., subject1, subject to till subject 15) and rows show the interaction techniques (e.g., interaction 1, interaction 2 till interaction 5). Value that is shown in each cell is performance time ( number of seconds took for each participant to interact with each interaction technique).  Does it make sense?

Comment: Right. Repeated measures ANOVA is the way to go, although there is a question about whether to transform your times to speeds. Some software would call the one-way repeated measures. Other software would call it two way (time and task) with repeated measures in one factor.